# Apply operation to multiple specified columns in data table

Tags: r, data.table, apply, variable-assignment

Let's say I have a data table with a bunch of columns. Many of these columns are in that weird Excel date format so they would look something like this: **47619**.

I can properly convert a column into a normal format by using this code:

```
dt[, old_date:= as.Date(old_date, origin = "1899-12-30")]
```

And I can repeat or add on to this line to do the same for the other columns. But what is the best way to perform this operation for all the specified columns at once? I'm not too experienced with using apply functions, but I figure that may be a place to start?

Comment: You can do `dt[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, origin = "1899-12-30"), .SDcols = nm1]` where `nm1 <- columsofInterest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, then loop through the `Subset of Data.table` (`.SD`), do the processing and then assign (`:=`) the output back to the columns

```
nm1 <- names(dt)[1:5] # change here
dt[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, origin = "1899-12-30"), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case we need this in one step, we can do

```
dt[, (names(dt)[1:5]) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, origin="1899-12-30"), .SDcols=1:5]
```

where `1:5` denotes the assumed columns to change.